# Polygon triangulation of regular $n$-gon consisting only of isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, contest-math, computational-geometry, polygons

As the title suggests today I solved a geometry problem and when I finished I had this question

> For which integers $n ≥ 3$ can one find a [polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) of regular $n$-gon consisting only of isosceles
> triangles?

My idea was analize when $n$ is even and try to find an algorithm, then do te same with $n$ odd, but I don't know how to proceed. Another approach was using graphs, but I think is even more complicated.

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the original problem and solution here. It was a USAMO problem so supposedly hard. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2008_USAMO_Problems/Problem_4